# Hover effects on nav link in gatsby

Tags: html, css

I am developing a static website using gatsby. Trying to bring hover effect while hovering a menu item in menu bar. I am having 4 classname in css Site-header, wrapper site-header__wrapper, nav__wrapper and nav__item. I have tried in both nav__wrapper.active and also in nav__item a. I couldn't able to achieve the result. Below I have added both the HTML and CSS code below. Can anyone guide me how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

```css
 * {
      padding: 0px;
      /* padding-bottom: 8px; */
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      background: radial-gradient(at top left, snow 0%, snow 100%);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .brand {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding-top: 12px;
      padding-right: 35%;
    }
    
    h3 {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-style: initial;
      font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande",
        "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .site-header {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 15px 10px;
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px snow;
    }
    
    .site-header__wrapper {
      padding-top: 4rem;
      padding-bottom: 6rem;
    }
    @media (min-width: 600px) {
      .site-header__wrapper {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 600px) {
      .nav__wrapper {
        display: flex;
        gap: 12px;
        align-items: center;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 0;
      }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 599px) {
      .nav__wrapper {
        position: relative;
        top: 100%;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        background-color: #d9f0f7;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-100%);
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease-out;
      }
      .nav__wrapper.active {
        display: inline-block;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
        position: relative;
        color: #0087ca;
      }
    }
    
    .nav__item a {
      transition: 0.4s;
      color: #111;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
      gap: 10px;
    }
    
    .nav__item a:hover{
      background-color: #ffffff;
      color: #EEA200;
      padding: 24px 10px;
      font-size: 50px;
    }
    .nav__toggle {
      display: flow-root;
    }
    @media (max-width: 599px) {
      .nav__toggle {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 1rem;
        top: 1rem;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="site-header">
      <div class="wrapper site-header__wrapper">
        <h3 class="brand">Community Site</h3>
        <nav class="nav">
          <div class="nav__wrapper">
            <a class="nav__item" href="/Home">
              <h3>Home</h3>
            </a>
            <a class="nav__item" href="/Aboutus">
              <h3>What are we</h3>
            </a>
            <a class="nav__item" href="/Contactus">
              <h3>Contact Us</h3>
            </a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. You have a space in `:hover`
2. You're pointing the `nav__item` child as `a` instead of `h3`

I've done it in this way and it worked

```
.nav__item > h3 {
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: #111;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
  gap: 10px;
}

.nav__item > h3:hover{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #EEA200;
  padding: 24px 10px;
}
```